# How can data be provided to a running generator?

Tags: javascript, generator

I wanted to provide data to running generator.

This is just JavaScript code and code itself can run any Browser console.

```
function* getNumbers() {
  yield 1
  yield 5
  yield 10
}
// retrieving
const getThoseNumbers = getNumbers()
console.log(getThoseNumbers.set())
console.log(getThoseNumbers.update())
```

I expect next `yield` values like 5 or 10.
But I am getting following error messages

- TypeError: getThoseNumbers.set is not a function
- TypeError: getThoseNumbers.update is not a function

Comment: Why do you expect [generators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Generator) to have `set` or `update`?

Comment: If you expect the next yielded value, use the `.next()` method? But that *gets* data from the generator, instead of providing data *to* the generator. I have no idea what you intend `set ` or `update` to do.

Comment: If you truly want to "provide data to the generator" you can actually provide a value when you call next to modify some internal state. [Here's a MDN article on it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators). At the bottom there's a part about advanced generators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function* getNumbers() {
  yield 1
  yield 5
  yield 10
}
// retrieving
const getThoseNumbers = getNumbers()
// console.log(getThoseNumbers.set()) - Uncaught TypeError: getThoseNumbers.set is not a function
// console.log(getThoseNumbers.update()) - Uncaught TypeError: getThoseNumbers.update is not a function

// You should call `next()`
console.log(getThoseNumbers.next()) // 1
console.log(getThoseNumbers.next()) // 5
console.log(getThoseNumbers.next()) // 10
```

You should call `next` and it is the way you can get next generator.

Comment: `next()` doesn't return the plain numbers though

Comment: I know. If you run `code snippet` you will see what `next()` returns

Answer (score 0):

An iterator (like the one you're creating when you call a generator function) has one property for getting the next value: `next`. `next` is a method that continues the generator until the next yield or return, and returns whatever value is yielded or returned in an object. The return object has two properties: `value` and `done`. `done` is a boolean that becomes true when the generator has completed.

Notice that none of this is `set` or `update`.

Comment: No, a generator has methods `next`, `throw` and `return`. It doesn't have a `done` property.

Comment: Yep, sorry, I explained that poorly. I edited my post to try and clarify.